# ElasticSearch filtering request

Tags: elasticsearch

I have got the example of the request to ES:

```
POST /fnh_main/main/_search?size=0
{
    "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "query" : {
                        "match_all": {}
            },
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_bounding_box": {
                            "location": {
                        "top_left" : "73.343091,-108.596992",
                        "bottom_right" : "-14.212892,139.957700"
                                        }
                                            }
                             }
                            } 
              },
    "facets" : {
        "places" : { 
            "geohash" : {
                "field" : "location",
                "factor" : 0.1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a few fields I want to filter this request:

- type (can be H, HO, А)
- pricetype (can be S, LT, ST)
- beds (can be 1,2,3,4,5, >6)
- price (can be a range)

I want to be able to filter the request with any of this parameters. The request can be for example:

- type - any
- pricetype - S
- beds - >6
- price - 100-200

I want to get the result that matches All this parameters.

Two days of brainstorming didn't give any result...

What is the best way to write this request? Maybe somebody can help me with it, will appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bool filter. In the bool filter you put all the filtered values in separate must condition.

For more information refer http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html